# matplotlib.pyplotの回帰直線でlinestyleが変わらない

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

matplotlib.pyplotを使って単回帰直線を表示させようとしています。(plt.plotを使っています。)
しかしlinestyleを設定しても回帰直線の両端が若干変わっているだけでほとんど変わっていません。
解決方法を教えてください。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 該当プログラムのソースコード(データ付き)をテキストで提示してください。あとはこの辺の記事を参考に。[matplotlibのめっちゃまとめ](https://qiita.com/nkay/items/d1eb91e33b9d6469ef51), [早く知っておきたかったmatplotlibの基礎知識、あるいは見た目の調整が捗るArtistの話](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/08dc0b8c5704c94eafb9), [matplotlibでのプロットの基本](https://qiita.com/KntKnk0328/items/5ef40d9e77308dd0d0a4), [pythonのmatplotlibの使い方をまとめてみた](https://qiita.com/renesisu727/items/24fc4cd8fa2635b00a0d)

Comment: もしかして散布図の点と回帰直線を同じ色で表示していて、散布図が散布しておらず回帰直線とほとんど同じなのでは？